What techniques are available to solve this 2nd-order ODE?
In Toward the Theory Of the Electroweak Phase Transition by Dine, Leigh, et. al they solve the 2nd-order ODE:

but I can't undestand how they have approximated an answer here? Both Laplace transforms and the homogenous ODE fail due to either the $\frac{1}{R}$ term and the boundary condition that $\frac{d \phi}{dR} = 0$ at $R = 0$. If this problem isn't solvable analytically what numerical techniques are available?

I would guess that it's some kind of Runge-Kutta numerical integrator to find $\Phi$ followed by some simple curve-fitting, but I don't know for sure.

Images aren’t accessible to everyone; you should really type out the relevant equations with MathJax.

Renaming $\Phi\equiv y$ and $R\equiv x$ and changing dependent variable to $z=xy$, you get $z''=z/x-3z^2/2x^2+\alpha z^3/2x^3$. Wouldn't the MSE be a better fit for the question? There is hardly any physics here.

If this problem isn't solvable analytically what numerical techniques are available? See Numerical methods for ODEs

A systematic treatment of the problem is available in Ch XIV on nonlinear equations of 2nd order of Ordinary Differential Equations
by E L Ince downloadable for free.
