Is it possible to derive an initial value for a field or have I reached a numerical limit?
The effective potential of the Higgs field  can be written in the form: $$V_{e} = \frac{M^2(T)}{2} \phi^2 - ET \phi^3 + \frac{\lambda_0}{4}\phi^4$$
We can parameterise this using $\phi = \frac{M^2}{2ET} \Phi$ and $x = \frac{X}{M}$ to rewrite the Lagrangian for this field as: $$ L = \frac{M^6}{4E^2T^2} \left[ \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu} \Phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2} \Phi^2 + \frac{1}{2} \Phi^3 - \frac{\alpha}{8}\Phi^4\right]$$
Where we define $\alpha = \frac{\lambda_0 M^2}{2E^2T^2}$. This enables us to write the field equation for $\phi$ as: $$\frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \rho^2} + \frac{3}{\rho} \frac{d \Phi}{d \rho} = \Phi - \frac{3}{2} \Phi^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2} \Phi^3$$
with boundary conditions $\Phi(\infty) = \Phi_{fv}$ and $\frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}|_{\rho=0} = 0$.
Using 4th order Runge-Kutta integration I can plot $\Phi(\rho)$, though I have to specify both $\Phi(0) =\Phi_{0}$ and the value of $\alpha$. For large $\rho$, the LHS of the field equation becomes 0, and thus through factorising it is clear that $\Phi_{fv}$ reduces to either 0, or $$\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{9-8\alpha}}{2\alpha}.$$ Is this as far as I can get in solving the field equation numerically or can I use this to determine $\Phi_{0}$ and have a function where I can put in just $\alpha$ and it would return $\Phi(\rho)$. This is similar to what is done on Pg.17 of Towards The Theory Of The Electroweak Phase Transition by M. Dine, R. Leigh et al, though I can't see how they make this last jump to purely a function of $\alpha$
EDIT: In re-reading the paper I can see that the assumption is made that $\Phi$ tends to 0 as $\rho$ tends to infinity. However my code doesn't give this limit for any sensible value of $\alpha$, instead the limit is positive. I have attempted the shooting method via bisection to try and solve this but I can't get a sensible result. Is the limit as $\rho$ tends to infinity not the function of $\alpha$ I have derived? The following is my integrator, if it is helpful:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = ["Liberation Serif"]
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100 # set to >300 for good quality graph

Φ_0 = 4
u_0 = 0
alpha = 0
dρ = 0.01 
ρ = np.linspace(0.01,20.01, 2000)

Φ = np.zeros(len(ρ))
u = np.zeros(len(ρ))

Φ[0] = Φ_0
u[0] = u_0

def f1(ρ, Φ, u):
    return u

def f2(ρ, Φ, u):
    return (-3/ρ)*u + Φ - (3/2)*(Φ)**2 + (alpha/2)*(Φ)**3

for i in range(0, len(ρ)-1):
    
    k1Φ = f1(ρ[i], Φ[i], u[i])
    k1u = f2(ρ[i], Φ[i], u[i])
    
    k2Φ = f1(ρ[i] + (dρ/2), Φ[i] + (dρ/2) * (k1Φ), u[i] + (dρ/2) * (k1u))
    k2u = f2(ρ[i] + (dρ/2), Φ[i] + (dρ/2) * (k1Φ), u[i] + (dρ/2) * (k1u))
    
    k3Φ = f1(ρ[i] + (dρ/2), Φ[i] + (dρ/2) * (k2Φ), u[i] + (dρ/2) * (k2u))
    k3u = f2(ρ[i] + (dρ/2), Φ[i] + (dρ/2) * (k2Φ), u[i] + (dρ/2) * (k2u))
    
    k4Φ = f1(ρ[i] + dρ, Φ[i] + dρ * k3Φ, u[i] + dρ * k3u)
    k4u = f2(ρ[i] + dρ, Φ[i] + dρ * k3Φ, u[i] + dρ * k3u)
    
    Φ[i+1] = Φ[i] + (dρ/6)*(k1Φ + 2* k2Φ + 2*k3Φ + k4Φ)
    u[i+1] = u[i] + (dρ/6)*(k1u + 2* k2u + 2*k3u + k4u)


plt.plot(ρ, Φ, color="black", linewidth = 1.5)
plt.title("4th Order Runge-Kutta Solution for Φ(ρ)", fontsize = 14)
plt.show()



Related by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/832451/25301
